# ¿Como realizar Querys que muestren un dato de la fila de la llave foranea relacionada?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Buenas tardes 
Tengo un inconveniente con Mysql, necesito el query a la tabla factura que estoy realizando me muestre el nombre de los ID de las llaves foraneas que tengo representadas, por ejemplo:

---

TABLA FACTURA

**IdFactura**

1

**IdPersona**

6

**IdViaje**

4

---

TABLA PERSONA

**IdPersona**

6

**Nombre**

Jose

---

TABLA VIAJE

**IdViaje**

4

**Viaje**

A

---

### Necesito que el query me muestre :

**IdFactura**

1

**Nombre**

Jose

**Viaje**

A

---

Trate de hacer un query con selects anidados pero solo pueden devolverme 1 fila, me lanza un error si la tabla de facturas tienen más registros. 
Les agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Uniendo las tablas con **inner join**

```
select f.IdFactura, p.Nombre, v.Viaje  
    from factura f 
         inner join persona p
      on f.IdPersona = p.IdPersona
         inner join viaje v
      on f.IdViaje = v.IdViaje
```

[***Ver Ejecucion***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa2e9/1/0)